# Extract username from localStorage Typescript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage

I m still new with Typescript, i want to output only **username** from this localStorage:

```
localStorage.getItem('currentUser')
```

which currently outputing:
{"**username**":"root","**password**":"root"}

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: Convert the string back to an object using `JSON.parse`:

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
console.log(user.username);
```

(Note: this applies to JavaScript in general, not just TypeScript)

---

**Details**

Items are stored in `localStorage` as strings. So to save an object in `localStorage`, you convert it to a string using `JSON.stringify(obj)`. (Whoever saved your user object to `localStorage` likely used this method.)

To convert back to an object, use `JSON.parse(str)`. Note that this can throw an exception if the string isn't a valid JSON representation of an object.

Example of all that with your user object (it's also valid JavaScript if you remove type declarations):

```
interface IUser {
  username: string;
  password: string; // please don't do this in real code
}

function saveCurrentUser(user: IUser): void {
  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
}

function getCurrentUser(): IUser {
  var userStr = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  try {
    return JSON.parse(userStr);
  } catch (ex) {
    return null; // or do some other error handling
  }
}

var user = { username: 'root', password: 'root' };
saveCurrentUser(user);

// elsewhere...
var savedUser = getCurrentUser();
if (savedUser) {
  console.log('Current user: ' + savedUser.username);
} else {
  console.log('Current user not found');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the JSON string back to an Object with **`JSON.parse`**

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```

and then you can access the username field in it

```
if(user){
   console.log(user.username);
}
```